# Having trouble getting distinct and Case statement working in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I execute the SP, I get this error message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

I tested the SQL without the case statement and it works, it returns everyone that is an admin.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRoles]
AS
DECLARE @num varchar(25),
@reportid Decimal,
@dom varchar(10)
set @reportid = 1
set @dom = 'use5'

SELECT @num = 
Case @reportid

 WHEN 1 THEN
  'select distinct u.id as userId, u.domain, u.isAdmin, u.email, u.canReport, a.[site],
  a.bldgNum, a.dataCenterNum, l.shortName, l.[description], a.canApprove, a.canComplete
  from locAdmin a inner join location l on (a.site=l.site and a.bldgNum = l.bldgNum 
  and a.dataCenterNum = l.dataCenterNum) right outer join [user] u on u.id=a.userId 
  and u.domain=a.domain where u.isAdmin = 1'

 End

 EXEC (@num)
```

Also distinct doesn't filter out duplicate userid for some reason too. Some of the Userids are inputted 3x depending on what access they have (That's the way it is setup before I came in)

Comment: You've set @num as varchar(25), then you set the value to a string that is way longer than 25 characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have limited `@num` to 25 characters - but the string you're setting it to is much longer than that - it'll be truncated
(also: *`@num` is a very odd and potentially misleading name for this - it suggest something numeric - and this is really more of a SQL statement or something - use the principle of least surprise when naming your variables!*)

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @stmt NVARCHAR(2000)
.....

SELECT @stmt = 
   CASE @reportid
      WHEN 1 THEN
          N'select distinct u.id as userId, u.domain, u.isAdmin, u.email, u.canReport, a.[site],
  a.bldgNum, a.dataCenterNum, l.shortName, l.[description], a.canApprove, a.canComplete
  from locAdmin a inner join location l on (a.site=l.site and a.bldgNum = l.bldgNum 
  and a.dataCenterNum = l.dataCenterNum) right outer join [user] u on u.id=a.userId 
  and u.domain=a.domain where u.isAdmin = 1'

 EXEC (@stmt)
```